# VBA Excel - Call macro using buttons

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have written the following macro that calls a Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() if I confirm that I want to run it. Please find below the first part of the code:

```
Sub test()
Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult

result = MsgBox("Run Macro?", vbYesNo, "Excel VBA")

If result = vbYes Then
    Call Worksheet_Calculate
End If

End Sub
```

The second code, which is Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(), shall copy the result of the calculation performed in B2 and paste it in C2 as well as add a timestamp to D2. Columns C and D are populated as values in B2 change, so that I get a list of results and timestamps in C3 and D3, C4 and D4 etc. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets(1).Cells(lastrow, 2)
        .Offset(1, 0) = Cells(2, 1).Value
        .Offset(1, 1) = FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongTime)
    End With

End Sub
```

The problem that I am facing is related to the fact that my Public Sub Worksheet_Calculate() is called only once and whenever I recalculate the value of B2 nothing happens.

Is there a way to a) keep second code activated or b) have a button(s) or a tickbox that would activate/deactivate the second code?

Hope it makes sense, thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you have the `Worksheet_Calculate` code, in a sheet code module or regular code module?

Comment: @BigBen, I have both codes in regular code module as I wanted my code to be available in any workbook I open. My intention was to have a button in the ribbon. Thanks!

Comment: @BigBen, I have never used it before but I will do some research and try to understand the idea behind it, thank you!

Comment: By "activate the second code", you want the second code to execute upon workbook calculation, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Worksheet Calculate Event

This is what you put into **Module1**, or what ever you will call your Module. This is a normal module created with Add Module. I've left the name of the test program intact, but I changed the other because it is used for worksheet events, particularly the **Worksheet Calculate event**. The **test** program and the variable `blnCalculation` enable or disable the whole thing, so in the beginning nothing will be happening before you enable it. You can create a button for it and in its **Click event** just add `Module1.test` or just run it from **Macros**.

```
Option Explicit

Public TargetValue As Variant
Public blnCalculation As Boolean

Sub test()
    Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult
    result = MsgBox("Run Macro?", vbYesNo, "Excel VBA")
    If result = vbYes Then
        blnCalculation = True
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
      Else
        blnCalculation = False
    End If
End Sub

Sub SheetCalculate()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Cells(lastrow, 2)
            .Offset(1, 0) = .Parent.Cells(2, 1).Value
            .Offset(1, 1) = FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongTime)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

And the following is what you put into each sheet code aka Object module, which you get by double-clicking on it in VBE. The **Worksheet Calculate event** happens each time Excel 'decides' to calculate a worksheet, which is in your case probably guaranteed because you say that there is a formula in `B2`, so the event will happen **every time `B2` gets calculated**. But it won't run the `SheetCalculate` program unless the **value has changed** which is checked with the `TargetValue` variable.
The **Worksheet Activate event** happens on a worksheet e.g. each time when you select it in the tab. In this case it is used to pass the new `B2` value from the newly selected worksheet to the `TargetValue` variable.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Module1.blnCalculation Then _
    Module1.TargetValue = Me.Range("B2").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Module1.blnCalculation Then
        If Me.Range("B2").Value <> Module1.TargetValue Then
            Module1.SheetCalculate
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much! Sorry, I haven't been online in the last couple of days, I will review your solution and try to understand it and will definitely let you know, thanks again!